# How do I check if a string contains a certain word and then delete that said word?

Tags: c#, replace, contains

I wanted it to work like this

```
sentence: "random sentence correct"

result: "random sentence"
```

Here is my current code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < answers.Count; x++)
{
    if(answers[x].Contains(" correct"))
    {
        answers[x].Replace(" correct", "");
        keys.Add(answers[x]);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't replace the said word for some reason

Or if it's impossible. Can I just delete the last word of the string?

So if the string is "this is a sentence correct"

the result will be "this is a sentence"

Comment: Define what the last word is. Everything behind the last whitespace? Or something more failsafe?

Comment: the last whitespace and everything behind it

Comment: `answers[x] = answers[x].Substring(0, answers[x].LastIndexOf(" "));` But be aware it only works in the tight definition you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answers[x] = answers[x].Replace(" correct", "");
```

every string manipulation function(like Replace in this example)   returns a new string since strings are immutable in c#

you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

Comment: I see, but is there no way for me to delete the last word of a sentence of a string?

Comment: that's a whole different question,

Comment: you can count " " (spaces) and delete the last area after the last " " (space) character

Comment: @hndsmkkgr: you have noticed that the answer does not use your code but appends `answers[x] =`? Because your comment suggests that you have overlooked that detail and you don't understand why you have to re-assign this string to the place where the old string was.